# Questions about the use of internal app files in android

Tags: java, android

I have some doubts about deployment an app in Google Play. I'm using Eclipse to work and my application needs some XML files store in `data/data/my_app/files/`.

1. When I use the AVD I can storage the files directly on `data/data/...` directory, but when I use my cellphone the directory is not open, why?
2. Suppose I use the AVD and storage the files on `data/data/...` directory, when I deploy my app to Google Play, those files will be accessible by my app. Will those files be accessible by anyone who download my app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use the AVD I can storage the files directly on data/data/... directory, but when I use my cellphone the directory is not open, why?

Security. The piece on Android that **`adb`** talks to has elevated privileges on an emulator.

> Will those files be accessible by anyone who download my app?

Generally no, for the same reason why they are not accessible to you per question #1. Users who root their devices will be able to get to files on internal storage. Otherwise, they cannot.

I wrote a blog post series a while back on the various storage options in Android and their characteristics, including [one on internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), that might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically I need those files to load data and to storage a favorite option. How can I do those two things without using external files? Using databases, seems to complicated for me to for only these two things.

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel: Databases are files. `SharedPreferences` are files. Everything that is locally persistent is a file. Hence, to persist data locally, you will need to use files. I do not know what "external files" means, and I do not know what your concern is regarding "external files".

Comment: To load the data of my application I need to read some XML files. The first time I try to storage and read them they were in my app code, but I cannot reach them. Then I read that I need to storage them in `data/data/...`, but if I cannot access those files freely then my app never load the data I need. Can I storage and read those file, for example, in the `res` directory?

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel: "but I cannot reach them" -- I have no idea what this means. Your app can read and write from its portion of internal storage. "if I cannot access those files freely" -- I have no idea what this means. Your app can read and write from its portion of internal storage. If you are expecting both the app and the user to have access to the files, [use external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel: "Can I storage and read those file, for example, in the res directory?" -- there is no `res/` directory. Your *project* may have a `res/` directory, but there is no such directory on the device, just as there is no directory containing Java source code on the device. Resources are packed into the APK file. Your app can read resources, but you cannot write to resources, and the user cannot readily access resources. Resources are also publicly readable by any app on the device that chooses to.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I have an idea to use in this case :D